# Rename files to match directory name

Tags: shell, unix

I have an interesting problem which I hope can be solved easily by shell commands. I have a directory tree where the directory names are meaningful, and inside each directory are several files, including a .mp3 file.

I would like to batch rename all the mp3 files to match the name of the directory.

Eg the high level directory looks like this:

```
Seans-iMac% ls
2006.James Lovelock: Gaia’s Revenge
2006.Religion and stem cell research
2006.Stephen Schneider
2006.Tony Judt: Post-war Europe since 1945
2006.Water management
2007.'Here, Bullet'
2007.Alan Bennett
```

The contents of each subdirectory are similar, eg:

```
Seans-iMac% cd "2006.Religion and stem cell research"
Seans-iMac% ls
details.txt     lnl_20060605.mp3    synopsis.txt
```

I would like to change it to this:

```
Seans-iMac% ls
details.txt     2006.Religion and stem cell research.mp3    synopsis.txt
```

I've tried a **for** loop but can't seem to get the parameters right. To make it more complicated the directory names have spaces and some have single quotes.

Comment: please update question with your code so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that there is at most one mp3 file in each subdir, this should do it:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i"/*.mp3 "$i/$i.mp3"; done
```

Note the double quotes, that deal with spaces.

Comment: Perfect - it also handed the single quotes.

Answer (score 2):

```
for d in 2???.*
do
    mv "$d"/*.mp3 "$d/$d.mp3"
done
```

The glob pattern generates the directory names you're interested in, preserving spaces in the names.  The `mv` command assumes there is only one `.mp3` file in the sub-directory, so the first argument will expand to the correct file name (spaces will be preserved again), and the second argument has the desired form.  Note that the `*.mp3` is outside the double-quoted string; this allows file name expansion.  Note that the directory name (which may contain blanks) is always inside double quotes to avoid losing the blanks.

Be cautious about using mechanisms other than a glob to generate the directory names.  It's not that they can't be used; just that care is required.  Note that directory names containing newlines are apt to be even more problematic than spaces; I'd rename such directories so that they don't contain newlines (and the same applies to file names containing newlines too).  Leading and trailing blanks in names can be problematic too.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan for a very clear answer. I gave it to jop as he had the same answer and his Stack Overflow rating is far lower than yours. I do appreciate your detailed explanation. Sean

Answer (score 2):

I'm under the impression that you are using tcsh as a shell.
Since I'm not a big expert, the following spawns a bash shell and uses bash syntax.

```
bash -c 'find /path/to/root/dir -name \*.mp3 | while read file; do d=`dirname "$file"`; b=`basename "$d"`; echo mv -v "$file" "$d/$b.mp3";done'
```

This won't do any modification, it just echoes the command that would be executed. If, after double checking, it indeed does what you want, remove the `echo` in front of the `mv` command.

This has the same limitations of the above ones, if there is more than one mp3 files in the directory, the last (alphabetical) file will have the name of the directory.mp3 and all other mp3 files will be overwritten (read: lost).

The difference in this case is that the structure of the folders can be nested and not necessarily in one level.

Comment: Interesting observation about `csh` — based on the `%` in the prompts, no doubt.  I won't bother to do more than point at the FAQ about [`csh` programming considered harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).  Most people don't use C Shell for serious shell programming.

Comment: I'm using zsh. The machine is a new build and I have just installed the defaults at this point.